# HIbernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to execute a query using hibernate where the requirment is like

```
select * from user where regionname=''
```

that is select all the users from user where region name is some data 
How to write this in hibernate
The below code is giving result appropraitely

```
Criteria crit= HibernateUtil.getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("regionName", regionName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well as you alaready said you can either use the Criteria API or create a HQL query:

```
// Criteria
List<User> users = HibernateUtil.getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("regionName", regionName)).list();

// HQL
String query = "SELECT FROM User WHERE regionName = :region";
List<User> users = HibernateUtil.getSession().createQuery(query).setString("region", regionName).list();
```

Comment: I just wanted to show the alternative to the Criteria you are using in your example with a HQL query. If you are doing the same, what is your question then?

Comment: i am not getting the complete resultset with it

Comment: I don't see any problems with either the criteria or HQL. Have you tried to issue a SQL query directly and see if it returns what you want?

Comment: What is the HibernateUtil class? My eclipse doesn't recognize it

Comment: It is a helper class which you can find here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-helpers

Answer (score 1):

```
String hql = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE regionName=:regionName";
Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
q.setParameter("regionName", regionName);
List result = q.list();
```